# What is the source of a "with-contenv" shebang?

Tags: bash, shell, containers

Could someone give me a brief explanation or links to an explanation of this topic?
Info on the origination would be dandy. The only information that I could find is related to s6-overlay, which I have not yet used. Is this the origination of this?

of the use of this Shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/with-contenv bash
```

vs. this Shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

The second is what I use most of the time with bash.

The is a bash she-bang (shebang) question about a type of shebang.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/with-contenv bash
# your shellscript follows
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# this is my normal way of encoding the she-bang.

# Where to appropriately use?
```

I should note, that I did read "... just make use of with-contenv helper" and I was wondering if that is the first usage, or if it comes from another source like docker, w3c, or somewhere else.

Comment: A good place to start is to ask your operating system's package manager which package `/usr/bin/with-contenv` came from. If it says that it came from s6, then you know that the s6 documentation is authoritative.

Comment: ...indeed, honestly, that first part of the question is one you *need to be* answering yourself, because you're the only person here who's in a position to find out if you have the `s6-overlay` version of `with-contenv` or some completely unrelated program your friendly neighborhood sysadmin wrote and happened to give the same name.

Comment: I have no experience with it myself, but it seems to be explained here: https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay#container-environment

Comment: Even easier that using your package manager, open the file up in your editor of choice. Does it look like [the s6-overlay version of `with-contenv`](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/blob/master/builder/overlay-rootfs/usr/bin/with-contenv)? If so, then yes, it's the s6 version.

Comment: To be clear -- bash doesn't read your shebang, *no matter what its value is*, so this is only tangentially a question about bash. The shebang is read by your operating system when deciding what program to run; if you run `/usr/bin/env bash`, then the OS invokes `/usr/bin/env`, and tells it to find a version of bash to run. If you use `#!/usr/bin/with-contenv bash`, then the OS invokes `/usr/bin/with-contenv`, which presumably as its next argument takes the name of a program to run after doing... something. What that something is depends on what `with-contenv` is on your system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Indeed, this is related, and very specific, to the [`s6-overlay`](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) architecture. This is a tool for using the [`s6`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/overview.html) process supervisor inside of Docker containers.

In some more detail, Docker is otherwise not well-suited to running multiple services and daemons in the same container, and the general architecture of a supervisor is at odds with how Docker wants things. `s6-overlay` attempts to fix this, so that you can run services inside of a single Docker container.

As explained in [the documentation](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay#container-environment), `with-contenv` is a wrapper which makes sure the argument is run with the environment variables specific to `s6-overlay`.

Concretely, it uses [`s6-envdir`](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-envdir.html) to load the environment from `/var/run/s6/container_environment` before executing its argument (in this case, `bash`).

Comment: Extra historical context, [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/) is essentially a few minor (but important) improvements over runit, and [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) is a supervision suite that really integrates the daemontools philosophy of service supervision into debian. And [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) originated the idea of [envdir](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/envdir.html)